# Surf3D, example from ggRandomForests: Random Forests for Regression

Tags: r, regression, plot

I have a model and I want to use the `surf3D` function in R, and produce a plot similar to the following (the image is the example from "ggRandomForests: Random Forests for Regression").

Example data available at

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hho5sgwjhlk4185/data.csv?dl=0

```
rfsrc_data <- rfsrc(rtp~., data=data)
```

From this point, I understand that I need to create a partial surface and then use the surf3D similarly to the example from ggRandomForests: Random Forests for Regression, however, I am lost with the partial surfaces.

```
surf3D(x=srf$x, y=srf$y, z=srf$z, col=topo.colors(10),
 colkey=FALSE, border = "black", bty="b2",
 shade = 0.5, expand = 0.5,
 lighting = TRUE, lphi = -50,
 xlab="Lower Status", ylab="Average Rooms", zlab="Median Value"
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a bivariate partial dependency plot first. I believe the function you are after to create the object to pass to `plot3D::surf3D` is `ggRandomForests::partial.rfsrc`, `ggRandomForests::gg_partial_coplot` or `ggRandomForests::gg_partial` and you can actually call the plot object using the `plot` generic but, probably not a 3D object.

I would honestly recommend that, unless there is something specific that you are after in the ggRandomForests package, the [pdp package](https://bgreenwell.github.io/pdp/articles/pdp.html) is far more flexible for exploring partial dependency and can support randomForest or ranger objects, along with a large variety of other model object types. For bivariate partial dependency and associated 3D plots, see the section on **Multi-predictor PDP's** in the linked vignette.

Here is a quick worked example of creating a bivariate partial dependency plot, with pdp, using your data and random forests from the ranger package.

```
library(ranger)
library(pdp)

rtp <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/hho5sgwjhlk4185/data.csv?raw=1")

( mdl <- ranger::ranger(rtp~., data=rtp) )

bvpd <- pdp::partial(mdl, pred.var = c("pp", "mv"), 
                     grid.resolution = 40)                
  pdp::plotPartial(bvpd, levelplot = FALSE, zlab = "rtp", drape = TRUE,
                   colorkey = FALSE, screen = list(z = -20, x = -60),
                   palette = c("viridis", "magma", "inferno",
                   "plasma", "cividis"))
```

[image: Bivariate partial plot of pp and mv]

Comment: Thank you @Jeffrey Evans! I did not know that I could use pdp for 3d surfaces! Thank you, very beautiful!